# kernel compilation error on Debian testing

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, debian

I have been trying to compile Debian kernel 4.19 on a 64 bit machine.
I used the procedure which I has successfully used before on another laptop, but this time I keep getting an error.

After configuring the kernel, following the latest Debian wiki I used the command:

```
make -j`nproc` bindeb-pkg
```

from within the source dir and, after the compilation seemd to succeed, got the error:

```
INSTALL debian/headertmp/usr/include/asm/ (62 files)
chown: invalid group: ´root:root´
make[4]:*** [scripts/package/Makefile:83: intdeb-pkg] Error 1
make[3]:*** [Makefile:1380: intdeb-pkg] Error 2
make[2]:*** [debian/rules:7: binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot -u debian/rules binary subprocess 
returned exit status 2 
make[1]:*** [scripts/package/Makefile:80: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
make:*** [Makefile:1380: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
```

I have tried to use the old command make deb-pkg and got the same result.
The strangest thing is that it tries to install the kernel on the machine rather than just produce the Debian packages.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is probably a topic for unix.stackexchange.com (a sister site, targeted to Unix and Linux users). This site is for programmer questions. The problem is `chown: invalid group: ´root:root´`. Are you in a chroot / broken virtual machine? Or you have very old tools (which requires dot)

Comment: hello. Neither one. it's a fresh Debian install, just upgraded and the compilation phase is supposed to be carried out as a normal user. I compiled the kernel with the usuall make command and worked fine. also, what baffles me is that it tries to install the kernel rather than just produce the binary package.

Comment: It should "install" kernel in a separate directory, so that package could see where the file should be and create the binary file. `fakeroot` is one tool to make thinking the installer that they are installing packages as root. Try with `apt-get build-dep <kernel image package` to be sure you have all relevant packages for building kernel (and the debian binary)

Comment: thanks, that at least cleared part of the mystery. I think you were probably right about permissions. also the ongoing confusion between "make deb-pkg" and "make-kpkg" commands didn't help. as you would say "un casino".